# Insert multiple HTML form checkbox values in single database column

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox

I am making an HTML form using Bootstrap 4 that contains three multiple-choice questions, allowing the reader to choose more than one answer using checkboxes.

**Here is an example of one question in the form.**

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/survey/insert.php" class="was-validated" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <legend class="form-check-label" for="tmp-area"><b>Please select the nearest city, town, or area where you have detailed knowledge of roads, trails, and places on public land.</b></legend>

            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Black Canyon City, Bumblebee, Cortes Junction" />Black Canyon City, Bumblebee, Cortes Junction </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Bouse, Brenda, Parker" />Bouse, Brenda, Parker </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Kingman, Lake Havasu City" />Kingman, Lake Havasu City </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Littlefield, Masquite" />Littlefield, Masquite </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Arizona Strip, Parashant National Monument" />Arizona Strip, Parashant National Monument</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Tuscon, Winkelman" />Tuscon, Winkelman </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Buckeye, Rainbow Valley" />Buckeye, Rainbow Valley </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Tonto National Forest " />Tonto National Forest </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Coconino National Forest" />Coconino National Forest </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Apache Sitgreaves National Forest" />Apache Sitgreaves National Forest </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"> <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area" value="Prescott National Forest" />Prescott National Forest </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Here is an example of** `/survey/insert.php`

```
<?php
        //Database connection
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "name";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Taking all values from the form data(input)
        $tmp_area = $_REQUEST['tmp_area'];
        

        //Insert form data into table. Set table and columns.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Survey1 (tmp_area) VALUES ('$tmp_area')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
            echo "Your survey has been submitted";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        ?>
```

**The problem**

When the user selects multiple checkboxes, only a single checkbox value is added to the database column.

I would prefer that **ALL** checkbox values, that are selected by the user, insert into the **same** database column.

All examples and tutorials I have found online require that each checkbox have its own column. Or do not go into much detail on how to accomplish this.

My knowledge of PHP is limited and any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: This seems like it would not be good database normalization; you usually shouldn't serialize data or store multiple values in a single column unnecessarily. I think it would be a more efficient way of storing the data if you were to store each possible value as a bit in an individual column so that you can use the database to efficiently search or compare results without having to extract each row first.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Thats a really good point that I didn't think of. I can already see how that would be useful for this project. That would require about 40 database columns. My next step is to incorporate this with a Leaflet map and I will need those individual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change tmp_area to tmp_area[]

```
 <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="tmp_area"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tmp_area" name="tmp_area[]" value="Bouse, Brenda, Parker" />Bouse, Brenda, Parker </label>
 </div>
```

During Insert

```
// Taking all values from the form data(input)
$tmp_area= implode(",",$_REQUEST['tmp_area']); // Store this to your database
```

If you need your tmp_area , then use this to convert to array again

```
$tmp_area[] = explode(",",$your_tmp_area);
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works wonderful. Thank you so much. I was reading about this and couldn't figure it out.

The 'explode' is used for what exactly? For what reason would I want to convert to an array?

Comment: Maybe you need to show all the selected checkbox value somewhere , then you need to convert it back to array , so that you can loop through it and show the value

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you much! Everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a alternative way, If you can store real value in db.

Like this:

Change input type name to array type.

```
<input type="checkbox" class=".." id=".." name="tmp_area[]" value=".." />
```

Create array value before insert to your database.

```
$tmp_area = ""; // create a variable to store all data

$tmp_area = implode(',',$_REQUEST['tmp_area']); // convert array type to string
```

When you retrieve data you can,

```
$tmp_area[] = explode(",",$data_tmp_area_replace_here); // convert string data from database to array
```